# How to apply two kinds of Plot styles in single graph

Tags: plotting, color

My version is 9.0

I want to apply ColorData and Line Width styles at the same time, like the ColorTheme Function new in 10.0, but there is always errors.
Codes under here:

`a[x_] := Sin[x]
b[x_] := Sin[x - 2 Pi/3]
c[x_] := Sin[x - 4 Pi/3]
f[x_] := Max[a[x], b[x], c[x]]
g[x_] := Min[a[x], b[x], c[x]]
Plot[{f[x] - g[x], a[x] - b[x], a[x] - c[x], b[x] - c[x], b[x] - a[x],
   c[x] - a[x], c[x] - b[x]}, {x, 0, 5 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Dashed, Dashed, Dashed, Dashed, Dashed},
  PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, 
 AxesLabel -> {\[Omega] t, Subscript[u, Subscript[VT, 1]]}, 
 AxesStyle -> {{Arrowheads[{0, 0.025}], Italic, 12, 
    FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, {Arrowheads[{0, 0.025}], Italic, 12, 
    FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}}]`
And graph is
[image]

How can i make lines separately Dashed and Thick, and at the same time the graph can use ColorData for a different view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suspect this is a duplicate. Not sure if it is the most straightforward but, e.g.:

```
PlotStyle -> 
 Transpose[{ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[;; 7]], {Thick, Dashed, Dashed,
     Dashed, Dashed, Dashed, Dashed}}]
```

or, in the same vain:

```
PlotStyle -> 
 Thread[Directive[
   ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[;; 7]], {Thick, Dashed, Dashed, Dashed, 
    Dashed, Dashed, Dashed}]]
```